# "Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" error when connecting to Cloudant with PouchDB on Mobile Safari

Tags: safari, couchdb, mobile-safari, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to connect to a Cloudant server using PouchDB. CORS is configured properly:

```
{
  "enable_cors": true, 
  "allow_credentials": true, 
  "origins": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```

And I've tried connecting using the following methods:

Method 1:

```
var db = new PouchDB("https://[username].cloudant.com/database", {auth: {username: [username], password: [password]}});
```

Method 2:

```
var db = new PouchDB("https://[username]:[password]@[username].cloudant.com/database");
```

Method 3:

```
var ajaxOpts = {
    ajax: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Basic ' + window.btoa([username] + ':' + [password])
        }
    }
};

var db = new PouchDB("https://[username].cloudant.com/database", ajaxOpts);
```

I then attempt to sync and get the error: "Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers." I only get this error on mobile Safari though. Everything works properly on Desktop Safari and Chrome.

Any thoughts on what is causing this?